# XMPP or HTTP. Which one scales better?

Tags: http, xmpp

The author of *[Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery](http://professionalxmpp.com/)* claims that stateless protocols like HTTP are much better to scale, as servers dont have to exchange the state among them, while the author of *[XMPP The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521271.do)*, claims that XMPP can scale very much better than HTTP.

I'm mind buggled, which of them scales better than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, as usual, it depends. XMPP may have better scalability properties for some applications, and HTTP for others.

Since no details are provided, I can only provide an answer in the broadest sense possible. The most important factor of scalability, is if you can easily progressively handle more users / transactions / data. Since HTTP is the most popular protocol in the world, and so many people have experience with it, I believe HTTP scales better because there are more resources, knowledge and people available to make that happen.

Comment: The question is in terms of satefulness/statelessness of the 2 systems, and whether that might affect the scalability.

Comment: But even state is not hard to implement with HTTP. Cookies / sessions are a 'solved problem'. If one is implementing real-time push it _may_ get more difficult with HTTP, depending on the server-side solution. It's certainly a hack.